# jQuery Chosen Plugin - hiding already selected values

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Hope someone can help. I currently have a select drop down list composed in PHP. I am using the Chosen plugin to turn this into a nice tag cloud type setup with multiple selections.

Some of the option entries have the class "hidden". These should be set to display:none

When I then load Chosen, any option entries with the hidden class are indeed not visible, unless they are selected, at which point they are displayed.

Does anyone know how to get Chosen to not display certain elements that are already selected?

http://jsfiddle.net/Hgfub/1/

Thanks

*update* to explain my requirements in more detail: the hiding of some selected options in the select element is simply to hide that option from the user, even though we want the value passed back in the php post value as selected. It's not a security setup as they'd still see it in the source, it's just a visual thing.

Comment: If it's already selected, shouldnt adding the hidden class not show the elements?

Comment: Do you have some code? Maybe a jsFiddle so we can see exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry - been out of the office all week. I'll get some code up ASAP

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hgfub/1/

Comment: Anyone? I'd really appreciate some help on this one

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided on GitHub.

Solution here [GitHub response](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/637#issuecomment-5943882)

To detail, modify the SelectParser object to test for an added parameter. You can do something like this.

```
<option selected data-hidden="true">Some Option</option>
```

And then test for the presence before even including this option in Chosen:

```
if (option.text !== "" && option.getAttribute("data-hidden") !== "true") {
```

You can find that test in the SelectParser.prototype.add_option function.

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.